# Fix parentless commits after git svn clone

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I  have converted a Subversion repository into a git one with:

```
git svn clone --no-metadata --stdlayout --prefix svn/
```

it worked well, but I have some holes in the repository, I think that it means that git svn was not able to find the parents:

```
A----B---C---D (2.0)      E --- F --- G (2.1)
```

Here, the first commit of the 2.1 branch has no parent, but it should have the 2.0 branch as parent.

I tried rebasing, but it failed with conflicts, is there a way of fixing these links ?

I think here that it is not working because E also gets all the commits prior it. The content seems to be correct, but the history is not.

Comment: What do you mean by "it failed with commits"?

Comment: @Jubobs That's a typo sorry :( I meant conflicts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 2.1 branch has no parent because `git svn` could not find a parent.

This is usually caused by an SVN branch that was not created using `svn copy`, but by locally copying the files, then `svn add`ing and committing them.
In that case, the SVN commit does not include the information where it was copied from, so `git svn` cannot know what to use as the ancestor. This is a bad practice (in SVN), but it's too late now.

How to fix this:

As far as I can see, `git rebase` should indeed work in this case. Something like:

```
git checkout 2.1
git rebase 2.0
```

I just tested this: I created a simple SVN repo that created a branch as described above, cloned it using `git svn` and rebased the branch, and it worked.

If you are getting conflicts, there is something else getting in the way.
In that case, we can probably only help with a test case.

Can you create a minimal testcase by building a dummy repo? Or can you anonymize the repo using [`git fast-export`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-export)  with option `--anonymize`? Then please post the testcase somewhere.